# Как в телеграмм боте отправить "видео в кружке"?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Пишу на python, использую asyncio.
Пытаюсь отправить файл типа videoNote, использую команду:

```
await  bot.send_video_note(message.chat.id, video,
                           reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
```

Но он отправляет обычное видео.
Почитал в документации, возможно нужно указать длину или размер, но разве за меня это не делает aiogram?
Да и вообще разве у других не хватает просто этой команды?

Помогите, очень хочу увидеть как моё детище отправляет эти "кружки"

Comment: sendVideoNote нашел тут
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideonote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нету такого в боте, это только у пользователей кнопка есть записи видео, и его отправляет в кружке, у бота это аналог загрузки видео файла, т.е всегда прямоугольное